# How to fix this error "I can't write on file 'contents/Cabstract.aux'..." when compile scripts

Tags: errors

[image: point out error]

the thesis file is like this :

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"

\documentclass[master]{uestcthesis}
\title{abc}
\author{kevin}
\date{2016}{12}{11}
\begin{document}
\include{chapters/ChapterA}
\include{chapters/ChapterB}
\include{chapters/ChapterC}
\include{chapters/ChapterD}
%\include{chapters/ChapterE}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, you are trying to work with subdirectories, which is often confusing for startes. Simply put all tex files in the same folder, not specifying a special folder with your `include` statements. But i don't know `uestcthesis`, it might have a funny bone that leads to the error.

Comment: I suppose you are a student of that university and kknow the chinese language, have a look at the documentation of the class/template. I might explain what you need to do.

Comment: Have you checked if you have write permissions on the `contents` subdirectory? What happens if you quit the TeX front-end entirely, close all open files, and then restart your front end and attempt to recompile your document? Incidentally, do the files `ChapterA.tex`, `ChapterB.tex` ... `ChapterE.tex` exist, and are they located in the `chapters` subdirectory? Incidentally, your code is a bit confusing since it doesn't provide an `abstract` environment whereas the screenshot of the error message does suggest that LaTeX is trying to process an `abstract`.